# sql select based off multiple values

Tags: sql-server

We're using SQL Server 2008, a sample of the table below. I need to query the below table and only give me the link result if no code of 'C' exists, but because link 957 below already has a C code, I dont want 957 returned at all, I would just want 950 and 955.

```
link                      code
---------------------------------
957                         A
957                         B
957                         C
957                         D
955                         A
955                         B
950                         D
950                         E
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you didn't want to use a nested query, the following will also work:

```
SELECT     link
FROM       table
GROUP BY   link
HAVING     SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0
```

Comment: SUM(CASE WHEN CODE = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = 0 cause he doesn't want 'C'

Comment: I'm curious which is the faster query. I meant to my and to this. Can you test it with large amount of data and put a comment with the result times?

Answer (score 1):

Try with the following example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT link
FROM TABLE
WHERE link NOT IN (
        SELECT link
        FROM TABLE
        WHERE code LIKE 'C'
        )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NOT EXISTS()` on this,

```
SELECT  a.*
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.link = b.link AND
                    b.code = 'c'
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3570d/2)

But if you just want to get the `link` alone,

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.link
FROM    tableName a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (
            SELECT  1
            FROM    tableName b
            WHERE   a.link = b.link AND
                    b.code = 'c'
        )
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/3570d/3)